# Sentiment analysis of Italian sentences

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis, fasttext

If you have any experience on sentiment analysis, could you please tell me how I can analyse these sentences, which tool, library, module should I need?

```
I nostri test di laboratorio ti permettono di confrontare le migliori marche di Condizionatori attualmente disponibili sul mercato.

Emergenza alluvioni : notizie e provvedimenti
```

I know that many of you are English speaker native. There are so many tools for English language, less for Italian one. 
I have tried with Fasttext and it did not work. I also thought to build one from scratch, but I did not know how to do it, which elements should be taken into account (top words, adjectives, nouns, n-grams...) to create a dictionary. 
If you could please provide an example of sentiment analysis with an Italian sentence (or with the two that I shown above), it would be great to understand what I would need.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps something here can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169732/sentiment-analysis-of-non-english-texts

Comment: I already saw that question and all the material around the web. Probably I have been using the wrong module, library, installation but I have never had the opportunity to analyse the sentiment of a text in Italian, but only in English. So I would really appreciate if you could show me how to do it, which modules and libraries I will need

Comment: try this https://nicgian.github.io/Sentita/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jointly Spacy and HuggingFace.
For instance, for sentiment analysis, I used [this](https://huggingface.co/MilaNLProc/feel-it-italian-sentiment?text=Mi%20piaci.%20Ti%20amo) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sentita:

https://github.com/NicGian/SentITA

it's pip installable and it has a pretrained model to use (explanations are provided into the readme).